# Capistrano 3: "find ... -exec ..." command syntax in task

Tags: ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

I am trying to integrate this shell command into a Capistrano 3 after deploy task:

```
find /var/www/mysite/somepath/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

However, I am failing at the proper Ruby syntax. I have tried most conceivable combinations between:

```
execute :find, "#{deploy_to}/somepath/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;"
```

and

```
execute :find, "#{deploy_to}/somepath/", "-type d", "-exec", "chmod", "755", "{}", ";"
```

but invariably end up with the error: `find: missing argument to -exec`

Could anyone please help me with the proper way to separate the arguments of this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong commands, `:find` is for using ruby functions, but you want to use `find` of linux utilities. Please try following

```
execute "find /var/www/mysite/somepath/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \\;"
```

Don't forget in the last I have double slashes to terminate command. But there is more good way to do it using following commands

```
set :file_permissions_paths, ["app/logs", "app/cache"]
```

I was using it in my very old project like following

```
set :permission_method, :chmod
set :use_set_permissions, true
set :writable_dirs, ["app/cache", "app/logs"]
set :file_permissions_paths, ["app/log", "app/cache", "storage"]
```

I think don't set permission of everything is really good idea, but when I did first time I was also getting confused so long time ago I have used following task which will go throughly and change all permission as you wanted

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :check_permissions do
    on roles(:web) do
      execute "chmod -R 0777 #{release_path}"
      execute "echo 'finished'"
      execute " /bin/systemctl restart nginx"
      #execute "cd #{deploy_to}/current && /usr/bin/env rake countries:update RAILS_ENV=production"
    end
  end
end
```

It has many things you remove and try what you want to do. Please note these are very old code, even I don't remember what are they doing, as I am not using capistrano any more to deploy but mostly dockers.

Comment: Hi @KamalPanhwar, many thanks for your answer! With `:file_permissions_paths`i assume you mean this gem: https://github.com/capistrano/file-permissions ? Not sure how to get the behaviour I want (change _all_ directories under somepath), so I used your first version. This works great, but I had to use `execute` (remote) vs. `exec` (local).

Comment: I am sharing few snippets but I think the better way is to use file-permissions method, but I also sharing task which you can use.

Comment: Thank you for the snippets @KamalPanhwar - i've accepted your answer. Perhaps you can still edit your first snippet from `exec` to `execute` to prevent people from accidentally changing their local permissions ;)